# Simple derivative giving two different answers in accordance to the chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose I define a function $f(x)$ $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+{\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)}^2}$$ and
$$u(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Now, if I want to find out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_m}$ where $m\in[0,\infty)$, then I can do it in two ways
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_m}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial {u}'}.\frac{\partial u'}{\partial a_m}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}^2}}.2u'.\frac{\partial u'}{\partial a_m}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_kx^{k-1}.mx^{m-1}}{\sqrt{1+{(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_kx^{k-1})}^2}}$$
or 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_m}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u'}.\frac{\partial u'}{\partial x}.\frac{1}{u'}.\frac{\partial u}{\partial a_m}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k-1)x^{k-2}}{\sqrt{1+(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_kx^{k-1})^2}}.x^m$$

Why do I get different results? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial f/\partial a_m$? $f$ is a function of $x$. It looks like that the numbers $a_m$ are just constants

Comment: yes, but don't treat them like constants, treat $u=u(a_1,a_2,.....a_m......a_{\infty},x)$

Comment: Your first result looks correct. The second one fails because, in $$\frac{\partial u'}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial u'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},$$ both sides don't make sense; $u'$ is not a function of $u$, and $x$ is not a function of $u$.